# Is it possible to use a dual monitor setup when you're two Remote Desktop Sessions deep?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I have two identical monitors on my desktop PC, which is running Windows 7 Ultimate. I'm using RDP to connect to a Windows 2008 Server, checking the option to use all of my displays in the session. From this Windows 2008 Server machine, I'm opening an RDP session into a Windows XP Professional computer, again checking the box to use all of my displays in the remote session. It is not possible to connect directly to the Windows XP computer.

However, even though the "use all displays" option is checked all the way through, when I remote from the Windows 2008 Server into the Windows XP desktop, one of my monitors is displaying Windows 2008 Server and the other contains the remote session.

Is it possible to use both of my physical monitors in the Windows 2008 Server -> Windows XP session?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20609

Comment: @STTR Let me try. It's my work computer, but I do have admin rights. Perhaps I can install that package. Perhaps you should post that as an answer? Even if it doesn't work in my particular instance, it may help someone else.

Comment: My strange answers are removed. But if it should be no problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update enables you to use the new Remote Desktop Services features.

System requirements: Windows XP Service Pack 3

Update for Windows XP (KB969084) - Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update

mstsc version- 6.1.7600.16385, about- 6.1.7600 , RDP 7.0

[Update for Windows XP (KB969084)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160126204812/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20609)

System requirements: Windows XP Service Pack 3

Security Update for Windows XP (KB2483614) - Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update

mstsc version- 6.1.7600.16722, about- 6.1.7600 , RDP 7.0

[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11596](https://web.archive.org/web/20150712102001/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11596)

Last mstsc Windows XP SP3 - now.

## Enable the RemoteApp functionality in Windows XP:

[Update for Windows XP SP3 to enable RemoteApp](https://web.archive.org/web/20151108151159/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4465)

This package lets you to run many Windows XP productivity applications from a Windows 7-based PC using Windows Virtual PC or Remote Desktop Services with Remote Desktop Virtualization Host role service.

custom.rdp:

```
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
allow font smoothing:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
disableremoteappcapscheck:i:1
remoteapplicationname:s:<application name>
remoteapplicationprogram:s:<application full path>
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:<application param>
```

command line:

```
mstsc custom.rdp
```

Overview

The Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 client update enables you to use the new Remote Desktop Services features. These features are introduced in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2 and are available for computers that are running Windows Vista Service Pack 1 or Windows Vista Service Pack 2. After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.

add option `mstsc /multimon`

System requirements:

Supported operating systems: Windows XP Service Pack 2

[Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client) 6.0 for Windows XP SP2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160118051145/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21075)

System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows XP Service Pack 2

[Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client) 6.1 for Windows XP SP2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114201024/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7208)

command line:

requirement - RDC support RDP 6.0;6.1;7.0;7.1

```
mstsc /span
```

requirement - RDC support RDP 7.0;7.1

```
mstsc /multimon
```

Server side, command line:

```
wmic path Win32_TSClientSetting get * /format:list | more
wmic path Win32_TSClientSetting get MaxMonitors
wmic path Win32_TSClientSetting get MaxXResolution, MaxYResolution
```

RDP client version:

```
SigCheck %windir%\system32\mstsc.exe
```

SigCheck utility of a set of Sysinternals Suite:

[Sysinternals Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite),[Sysinternals Utilities Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/)

[Remote Desktop Connection 7 for Windows 7, Vista, XP](https://web.archive.org/web/20160126170455/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/08/21/remote-desktop-connection-7-for-windows-7-windows-xp-windows-vista.aspx)
Multimonitor Support:

```
XP SP3 RDC 7.0 ; XP SP3 RDC 6.1
     true      ;   spanning
```

Default.rdp save as New.rdp, add `use multimon:i:1`

Run:

```
mstsc new.rdp
```

Table: RDC version - RDP version - OS - update:

[image: Table: RDC version - RDP version - OS - update]

Alternative RD Client:

Multi RDP Client .NET

[http://multirdpc.codeplex.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20210920211241/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=multirdpc)

Optimizing Visual Studio 2010 and WPF applications for Remote Desktop

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217125908/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop.aspx)

Freeware Windows XP Aero Snap tools

[AeroShaft brings Aero Snap Windows 7 to Windows XP and Windows Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524090353/http://shanegowland.com/freeware/2011/aeroshaft-brings-aero-snap-to-windows-xp-and-windows-vista/)

[image: Aero Snap Window XP]

Comment: I was able to install it. It doesn't work, but I'm not going to discount this yet. I haven't tried to reboot the machine yet, and I'm not sure I want to try since I'm planning on working remotely over the weekend (and Monday, if the office is closed due to our weather). Monday, I'll reboot the computer at work and see if that does it.

Comment: @Thomas Owens Run: `mstsc /span`

Comment: `mstsc /multimon`

Comment: /span apparently works, but everything is centered between my two monitors. It effectively treats my two monitors as one big monitor. It's better than one monitor, though. I still haven't tried a reboot of the WinXP side, though.

Comment: @Thomas Owens Windows XP mstsc client version and RDP protocol?

Comment: I updated to the Remote Desktop Connection 7.0 that you linked to, rebooted my machine, and the best I can do is /span. It lets me use both of my physical monitors, but it treats them as one big monitor, so things like maximizing windows doesn't work (it takes up both monitors instead of one).

Comment: Create new .rdp file. Add `use multimon:i:1` run `mstsc new.rdp`

Comment: Multimon - uncertain by 110% : Windows XP SP3, RDP protocol ver 7, RDP client v 6.01; Easy print - .NET 3.5 SP1, XPS printer.

Comment: test in new mstsc (RDC 7) - `mstsc /multimon`

Comment: From one of your links: `Note: If you use RDC 7.0 to connect to XP or Vista you do not get new Windows 7 features like Windows Media Player Redirection etc. There is no way to get these features when connecting to XP or Vista.` It appears that span is the only option available when connecting to Windows XP. However, Windows XP, when connecting to newer operating systems, can have a multimonitor RDP session.

Comment: test `mstsc /multimon` after update?

Comment: Yes. And installing alternative RDP clients is not possible on the Windows server due to its configuration.

Comment: http://shanegowland.com/freeware/2011/aeroshaft-brings-aero-snap-to-windows-xp-and-windows-vista/

Comment: Install last mstsc update? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11596

Comment: span + Windows XP Aero Snap tools?

Comment: I can not install these other tools. The only thing I can (and did do) was update the RDP client on Windows XP from Microsoft. If you clean up your answer to clearly quote your source that says it's not possible to use multiple monitors when connecting to Windows XP, but that you can use /span with the recent updates, I can accept it.

Comment: There is something that depends on the components installed on the client and on the server side. I have a suspicion that multi-monitor support depends on the installed Net on the server side and the client. So dependent on. Net 3.5.1 SP1 Easy print. Depends on DirectX - RemoteFX. Do you have the possibility to install components on the server?

Comment: No. I only have access to my desktop computer (running Windows 7) and the endpoint desktop (running Windows XP SP3, fully updated to the latest .NET and RDP). The server is a restricted access security layer into a corporate network - I have 0 rights on it, other than to open RDP sessions into other computers.